# can x11vnc be used on cloud servers without a "real" display

Tags: xorg, vnc

x11vnc is a server for real X displays as described [here at a definitive reference site](http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/x11vnc_opts.html#opt-create). Does that mean it is exclusively for servers with a physical display?

Does that mean that I cannot use it for a cloud server, since normally they would not have a physical display accessible to customers?

I am getting the following error

> 06/12/2014 10:42:39 XOpenDisplay(":0") failed.
>
> 06/12/2014 10:42:39 Trying again with XAUTHLOCALHOSTNAME=localhost ...
>
> 06/12/2014 10:42:39 ***************************************
>
> 06/12/2014 10:42:39 *** XOpenDisplay failed (:0)
>
> - x11vnc was unable to open the X DISPLAY: ":0", it cannot continue.
> - There may be "Xlib:" error messages above with details about the failure.

The error is a result of applying the following:

> x11vnc -safer -localhost -nopw -once -display :0

That command is the appropriate command according to this ubuntu page: [VNC help, community page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC)

The same error results from the following

> x11vnc -create -safer -localhost -nopw -once -display :0

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 from a clean installation from a cloud service provider with a "desktop" added via `apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` in order to run applications which expect a GUI. Virtually the same software combination (Ubuntu + ubuntu-desktop + my application) worked fine with 12.04 and [tightvnc](http://tightvnc.com/) but since I get a grey screen in tightvnc after switching from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04, I decided to try X11.

Comment: I think you need to run an X server on the server if you're going to use DISPLAY :0. Is an X server running?

Comment: Issuing `startx` results in failure and the message "no screens found".

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is Xvnc.  It's an X server that displays to VNC instead of a monitor.
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/Xvnc4.1.html