# Which free remote system such as VNC or similar is known to work on 14.04 cloud

Tags: 14.04, vnc, cloud

Doing some trial and error `:(` on a [linode](http://linode.com).

I've tried `tightvnc` but get a grey screen with the identical setup I used to use with 12.04. I ran with 12.04 and `tightvnc` successfully for about 2 years.

I have an outstanding bug reported for `x2go` and 12.04 so I'm hesitant to use it with 14.04. The bug is unacceptably slow performance after a few hours of use. This is x2go bug # 465.

I considered [nomachine's free edition](https://www.nomachine.com/download/download&id=2) but their website says that "the free NoMachine 4 is designed to work the same across Windows, Mac and Linux and give users access to the physical desktop of the remote computer. If you need to create virtual desktops on demand, want to limit the logins to SSH, or are using NIS, Kerberos or other enterprise server functionalities, you need one of the NoMachine Enterprise server products". If my understanding is correct, a cloud server from [linode](http://linode.com) has no physical desktop provided to the customer so nomachine is recommending the paid-for product.

I tried `x11vnc` but have not succeeded and I have an unanswered problem for this method.
[My question for x11vnc and 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/557384/can-x11vnc-be-used-on-cloud-servers-without-a-real-display). `x11vnc` might also need a physical display.

Comment: Is it a requirement that you run Unity? Or is Xfce/Gnome fallback an option?

Comment: I don't need Unity but I do need a headless graphical desktop.

Comment: You could try: http://www.xrdp.org/ . I'm not sure why any of them are causing trouble though. They should all be fine.

Answer (score 4):

Below method works for me.

Install desktop with minimal packages.

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends ubuntu-desktop
```

Install few gnome packages to load VNC properly.

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-panel gnome-settings-daemon metacity nautilus gnome-terminal
```

Install vnc4server

```
sudo apt-get install vnc4server
```

Open **/usr/bin/vncserver**

Find **"# exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc\n\n".** line and add these lines below

```
      "# exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc\n\n".
       "gnome-panel &\n".
       "gnome-settings-daemon &\n".
       "metacity &\n".
       "nautilus &\n".
       "gnome-terminal &\n".
```

Start vncserver

```
vncserver
```

Afetr starting session , you could access VNC with your IP and session ( 12.34.56.78:1 )
[image]